# Inverting the Colors of a MapView

Tags: swift, mkmapview, mapkit

Is it possible to programmatically invert the colors of a `MKMapView`? I don't want to invert the colors on any other element though.

Comment: You mean appearance? 
You could change MKMapView appearance by `MKMapType` enumerator. Like 
`let map = MKMapView()
map.mapType = .Standard `
[documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKMapView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/MKMapType)

Comment: Otherwise, if you want to change colour (like make it dark) you may want to use 3rd party library - e.g. [MapBox](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-ios-sdk-legacy/) they [have](https://www.mapbox.com/api-documentation/#styles) such possibilities

Comment: @AlekseyPotapov that's what I ended up doing. If you add a answer I'll solve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Native Apple MKMapView appears only in one colour scheme. You may want to use 3rd party library - e.g. [MapBox](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-ios-sdk-legacy) they provide possibility to change [map style](https://www.mapbox.com/api-documentation/#styles).